# dual booting ubuntu without affecting recovery disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader, disk-management

I bought a new laptop with genuine windows 8 with a recovery partition built in. I need to install ubuntu without affecting to the current configurations.

This is how my partition table looks in windows. How should I free up memory to install ubuntu?

[image]

there are two recovery partitions. One with 500mb and the other with 8.34 gb. What is the purpose of two of them?

Answer (score 0):

one of the the larger partition contains the Windows 8 software. Whatever your computer came with day 1 is in that partition ready to install. Depending on your laptop that may include all of the bloatware installed by the manufacture (some have their stuff on a separate partition). The 500MB partition is kind of like a small write buffer, it. During recovery operations and factory resets it provides a minimum swap area for certain operations. At least this is my understanding of the purpose of the 500 MB section. Whenever I dual boot a computer I always make a small fat32 partition between the two OS's to prevent the file system of one from inadvertently corrupting the other. It is possible that this small partition serves that purpose as well. I hope that helps. If you want to keep windows 8 I would not touch either of those partitions to be on the safe side.